# Django AWS RDS MySQL Error: (2026, 'SSL connection error: error:00000001:lib(0):func(0):reason(1)')

Tags: python, mysql, django, ssl, amazon-rds

I'm having some trouble connecting to my AWS RDS Database from my Python/Django application. I'm getting this error when trying to run my application locally:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2026, 'SSL connection error: error:00000001:lib(0):func(0):reason(1)')
```

I couldn't find any answers online as I am not trying to connect via SSL.

My Database settings in `settings.py` is straightforward:

```
DATABASES = {
     'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
       'NAME': '<my db name>',
       'USER': '<my username>',
       'PASSWORD': '<my password>',
       'HOST': '<my aws host>',
       'PORT': '<my port>',
     }
}
```

I was getting the same error trying to access the MySQL RDS via terminal, but was able to resolve that error by adding `--skip-ssl` to the end of the command. I've looked around but haven't yet found a way to implement that same fix with my Django application.

This is my first time working with Python, Django and AWS (and also posting a question on stack overflow) so I apologize in advance if my terminology is off. Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: have you solved this?

Answer (score 2):

did you try

```
DATABASES = {
     'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
       'NAME': '<my db name>',
       'USER': '<my username>',
       'PASSWORD': '<my password>',
       'HOST': '<my aws host>',
       'PORT': '<my port>',
       'OPTIONS': {
            'skip-ssl',
       },
    }
}
```